# curl fails with error "data too large for modulus" when trying to fetch data with https and certificate files

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue in our github actions node.js build. There is a step where the build fetches a json file to synchronize node.js types, roughly like this:

curl --cacert certificates/ca.pem --key certificates/key.pem --cert certificates/cert.pem  https://my-api.my-backend-server.com/api-docs/swagger.json -o um_swagger_test.json

But when I try to run the above line locally, with all the necessary certificates in place as far as I can see, I get the error:

curl: (35) error:04067084:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:data too large for modulus

What does this mean? Is my local test setup likely wrong or could this indicate some other error on the server side? I tried to google the error "data too large for modulus" and there is very little useful info available. Time to start digging into OpenSSL source code, or how to make sense of this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Seems the problem was that I used the wrong certificates after all, and the certificates where probably the wrong size for data or something like that